# vertx writefile is not working

Tags: java, file, vert.x, writefile

Hey am running this code and in log it's showing File written but actually it's not writing anything while in reading operation it's reading data and showing in log. Writefile,copyfile etc are not working.

```
vertx.fileSystem().writeFile("testfile.txt", Buffer.buffer("Hello"), result -> {
                if (result.succeeded()) {
                    System.out.println("File written");
                    System.out.println(result.toString());
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Oh oh ..." + result.cause());
                }
            });
```

Comment: I think you should also share the read operation since this snippet does seem to work

Comment: This snippet works just fine for me. Since your file path is relative, have you checked the current working directory?